# Compute a conditional probability given a random parameter

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space. Consider a collection of real random variables $\{X(\gamma)\}_{\gamma\in [0,1]}$ defined on this probability space. Let $Y$ be a random variable taking values in $[0,1]$ and independent of the family $\{X(\gamma)\}_{\gamma\in [0,1]}$ . Am trying to show that, given  $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$,

$$P[X(Y)\in B\mid \sigma(Y)]=g \circ Y \quad (1)$$

with $\gamma\mapsto g(\gamma)=P[X(\gamma)\in B]$.

By the  [Doob–Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma) we know there exists measurable $g$ satisfying $(1)$, so the question is how to identify this $g$ with $\gamma\mapsto P[X(\gamma)\in B]$.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does $Y$ being "independent of the family" $\{X(\gamma)\}_{\gamma \in [0,1]}$ mean?

Comment: @Michael The pair $(Y,X(\gamma))$ is independent for each $\gamma \in[0,1]$.

Comment: Really?  That is much weaker than I expected. That would mean that if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are pairwise independent but not mutually independent, then $X_1$ is independent of the family $\{X_2, X_3\}$.

Comment: @Michael Ok sorry then $Y$ is independent from the $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ valued random variable $\omega\mapsto \{X(\gamma)(\omega)\}_{\gamma \in [0,1]}$.

Comment: Where does this exercise come from?  The function $g(\gamma)$ may not even be a Borel function!

Comment: @Michael Good point. You can assume $(\gamma,\omega)\mapsto X(\gamma)(\omega)$ is jointly measurable, so that $\gamma \mapsto P[X(\gamma)\in B]$ is measurable by Fubini’s theorem.

Comment: @Michael Assume $|X(\gamma)(\omega)|\leq M$  for all $(\gamma,\omega)$ for some $M>0$ so that there is no integrability issues.

Comment: How does this construction differ from one in your other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138752/a-law-of-large-numbers-for-conditional-expectations/4138865)?

Comment: @d.k.o. It is the same set-up indeed. Here am trying to understand why the conditional probability takes this form.

Comment: @Alphie If your comment to that question is valid, this is a fairly simple fact. See, for example Corollary 4.38 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=v_LStgZHfy0C&pg=RA1-PA80&dq=breiman+corollary+4.38&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmm9fo6trwAhUPahQKHbC6BugQ6wEwAnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=breiman%20corollary%204.38&f=false)

Comment: @d.k.o. Ah you mean the assumption that $X(\gamma)=f(\gamma,Z)$ for some rv $Z$! Then I must assume $Y$ independent from $Z$ to apply Corollary 4.28 with $\phi=f$ to obtain $E[X(Y)|\sigma(Y)]=E[X(\gamma)]\circ Y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a version of the functional monotone class theorem found in [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) (Theorem 6.1.3 on page 235), assuming that $(y,\omega)\mapsto X(y,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,1])\otimes \mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Consider the class $\mathcal{H}$ of all bounded, nonnegative, measurable functions on $[0,1]\times \Omega$ s.t. for $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[\varphi(Y,\,\cdot\,)\mid Y]=g(Y)\quad\text{a.s.},
$$
where $g(y)=\mathsf{E}[\varphi(y,\,\cdot\,)]$. Measurable rectangles $A\times B$ with $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $B$ is independent of $Y$, belong to $\mathcal{H}$ because
$$
\mathsf{E}[1_A(Y)1_B\mid Y]=1_A(Y)\mathsf{P}(B).
$$
Moreover, $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under addition, multiplication by a constant, and increasing limits (*by the (conditional) bounded convergence theorem*). It remains to show that
$$
\mathcal{P}=\{A\times B:A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), B\in\mathcal{F},B\perp \!\!\! \perp \sigma(Y)\}
$$
is a $\pi$-system that contains $[0,1]\times \Omega$. Then, $\mathcal{H}$ contain all bounded functions measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$.

---

In your case, $\varphi(y,\omega)=1\{X(y,\omega)\in B\}$ for some fixed $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask why $\varphi(y,\omega)=1\{X(y,\omega)\in B\}$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$? I don't see it.

Comment: @Alpha You may use the same argument, where you replace the class $\mathcal{H}$ with the class of bounded, measurable functions $\varphi$ with $\varphi(y_1,\,\cdot\,),\ldots,\varphi(y_n,\,\cdot\,)\perp \!\!\! \perp Y$ for any finite collection $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ of points in $[0,1]$ (*which means that* $\{\varphi(y,\,\cdot\,)\}_{y\in[0,1]}$ *is independent of* $Y$). Check the conditions of the theorem. As for the last condition (*closedness under increasing limits*) you may employ [this characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/808891) of independence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I had another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4150829/522332 and was wondering if you could help me. Thank you for your time.